# Custom History related list

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I created custom related history using visualforce page.

```
<apex:component controller="GenericHistoryComponentController">
<!-- Attribute Definition -->
<apex:attribute name="myObject" description="Object we wish to view the history of" type="SObject" required="true" assignTo="{!myObject}" />
<apex:attribute name="recordLimit" description="Number of lines of history to display" type="Integer" required="false" assignTo="{!recordLimit}" />

<!-- Object History Related List -->
<apex:pageBlock title="{!objectLabel} History">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ObjectHistory}" var="History" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Date"  value="{!History.thedate}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="User">
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!History.userId}"> {!History.who} </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Action"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!History.action}"/></apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

```
public class GenericHistoryComponentController {

// External variables
public SObject myObject {get; set;}
public Integer recordLimit {get; set;}
public static String objectLabel {get;}

// Internal Variables
public objectHistoryLine[] objectHistory; 

public static final Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mySObjectTypeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> myObjectFieldMap;
public static List<Schema.PicklistEntry> historyFieldPicklistValues;

public List<objectHistoryLine> getObjectHistory(){

    Id myObjectId = String.valueOf(myObject.get('Id'));
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objectDescription = myObject.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

    myObjectFieldMap = objectDescription.fields.getMap();
    objectLabel = String.valueOf(objectDescription.getLabel());

    //Get the name of thew history table
    String objectHistoryTableName = objectDescription.getName();
    //if we have a custom object we need to drop the 'c' off the end before adding 'History' to get the history tables name
    if (objectDescription.isCustom()){
        objectHistoryTableName = objectHistoryTableName.substring(0, objectHistoryTableName.length()-1);
    }
    objectHistoryTableName = objectHistoryTableName + 'History';

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult objectHistoryFieldField = mySObjectTypeMap.get(objectHistoryTableName).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Field').getDescribe();
    historyFieldPicklistValues = objectHistoryFieldField.getPickListValues();

    list<objectHistoryLine> objectHistory = new list<objectHistoryLine>();

    String prevDate = '';

    if (recordLimit== null){
        recordLimit = 100;
    }

    list<sObject> historyList = Database.query( 'SELECT CreatedDate,'+
                                                'CreatedById,'+
                                                'Field,'+
                                                'NewValue,'+
                                                'OldValue ' +
                                                'FROM ' + objectHistoryTableName + ' ' +
                                                'WHERE ParentId =\'' + myObjectId + '\' ' +
                                                'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC '+
                                                'LIMIT ' + String.valueOf(recordLimit));

    for(Integer i = 0; i < historyList.size(); i++){
        sObject historyLine = historyList.get(i);
        if ((historyLine.get('newValue') == null && historyLine.get('oldValue') == null) 
                || (historyLine.get('newValue') != null && !(string.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).startsWith('005') || string.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).startsWith('00G')))
                || (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null && !(string.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).startsWith('005') || string.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).startsWith('00G')))){
            objectHistoryLine tempHistory = new objectHistoryLine();
            // Set the Date and who performed the action
            if (String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate')) != prevDate){
                tempHistory.theDate = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate'));
                tempHistory.userId = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
                tempHistory.who = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
            }
            else{
                tempHistory.theDate = '';
                tempHistory.who = '';
                tempHistory.userId = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedById'));
            }
            prevDate = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('CreatedDate'));

            // Get the field label
            String fieldLabel = GenericHistoryComponentController.returnFieldLabel(String.valueOf(historyLine.get('Field')));

            // Set the Action value
               if (String.valueOf(historyLine.get('Field')) == 'created') {    // on Creation
                   tempHistory.action = 'Created.';
              }
              else if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null && historyLine.get('newValue') == null){ // when deleting a value from a field
                  // Format the Date and if there's an error, catch it and re
                  try {
                     tempHistory.action = 'Deleted ' + Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).format() + ' in <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>.';
                } catch (Exception e){
                     tempHistory.action = 'Deleted ' + String.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')) + ' in <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>.';
                }
              }
              else{  // all other scenarios
                  String fromText = '';
                if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null) {
                     try {
                          fromText = ' from ' + Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue')).format();
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                          fromText = ' from ' + String.valueOf(historyLine.get('oldValue'));
                     }
                }

                String toText = '';
                if (historyLine.get('oldValue') != null) {
                    try {
                         toText = Date.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue')).format();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                         toText = String.valueOf(historyLine.get('newValue'));
                    }
                }
                if (toText != ''){
                    tempHistory.action = 'Changed <b>' + fieldLabel + '</b>' + fromText + ' to <b>' + toText + '</b>.';
                }
                else {
                    tempHistory.action = 'Changed <b>' + fieldLabel;
                }
               }

               // Add to the list
               objectHistory.add(tempHistory);
        }
     }

     List<Id> userIdList = new List<Id>();
     for (objectHistoryLine myHistory : objectHistory){
         userIdList.add(myHistory.userId);
     }
     Map<Id, User> userIdMap = new Map<ID, User>([SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id IN : userIdList]);

     for (objectHistoryLine myHistory : objectHistory){
         if (userIdMap.containsKey(myHistory.userId) & (myHistory.who != '') ){
             myHistory.who = userIdMap.get(myHistory.who).Name;
         }
     }

     return objectHistory;
}    

// Function to return Field Label of a object field given a Field API name
public Static String returnFieldLabel(String fieldName){

    if (GenericHistoryComponentController.myObjectFieldMap.containsKey(fieldName)){
        return GenericHistoryComponentController.myObjectFieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
    }
    else {
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry pickList : historyFieldPicklistValues){
            if (pickList.getValue() == fieldName){
                if (pickList.getLabel() != null){
                    return pickList.getLabel();
                }
                else {
                    return pickList.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}

// Inner Class to store the detail of the object history lines    
public class objectHistoryLine {

    public String theDate {get; set;}
    public String who {get; set;}
    public Id userId {get; set;} 
    public String action {get; set;}
}
```

}

```
<apex:page standardController="Coaching_Report__c" extensions="fExtension">
<apex:form>
<apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageblocksection  title="Information">
<apex:outputField value="{!currentFCR.Manager_vod__c}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection>
<apex:pageblocksection title="fleet">
<apex:outputField value="{!currentFCR.Employee_vod__c}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection>
<c:GenericHistoryComponent recordLimit="50" myObject="{!Software_License__c}"/>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The issue is I get two blocks on my visualforce page because of pageblock on component and pageblock on my visualforce.I want to get rid of my pageblock on component.Any ways to remove it

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `dataTable` in the component?

Answer (score 1):

Try making in a PageBlockSection, as long as you reference it inside a PageBlock on the VF page it should work.

**Component:**

```
<!-- Object History Related List -->
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="{!objectLabel} History" collapsible="false">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ObjectHistory}" var="History" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Date"  value="{!History.thedate}"/>
            <apex:column headerValue="User">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!History.userId}"> {!History.who} </apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Action"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!History.action}"/></apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```