# How do I see the audit trail for Products added to a Opportunity

Tags: history-tracking, opportunity-history, field-history

How do I see the audit trail for Products fields e.g. change in quantity or change in salesprice, for a Product added to a Opportunity

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no field history tracking for opportunity products.Please vote for this [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000j08LAAQ).You could do this via custom history visualforce section.please find the [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/19436/custom-history-related-list)